# How to make a Spring form:checkbox to readonly using javascript

Tags: javascript, spring

I want to make spring form:checkbox tag to readonly using java script. I can make it to disable using 
 document.getElementById('id').disabled = true;
But then it doesn't set value to command object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A disabled form input field is indeed not submitted. You could do one of the following:

- make the checkbox readonly rather than disabled.
- add a hidden input field with the same name as the checkbox and with the checkbox's value, when disabling the checkbox. Just make sure to remove this hidden field when re-enabling the checkbox again.
- re-enable the disabled checkboxes at submit time, using JavaScript

Comment: Good answer, however mention to author that he need to apply just one of those three possible solutions in order to get what he wants. So "You could do one of the following:" instead of "You could" - just to be clear.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I've improved my answer, following your advice.

Comment: @JBNizet Great answer. It shows many path to solve the problem. I used third one in my scenario. Thanks.